# Functions whose zero extension are in $H^1$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Let $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ be the classical Sobolev space on an open set $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$. Denote by $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ the closure of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$.

**Question.**

Suppose that the extension by zero of $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, $\Omega$ bounded, is in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$. It is known that this implies that $u\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ when $\Omega$ is, e.g., $C^1$. But I wondered if it is known a characterization (an if and only if) of the open sets for which this statement is true. In any case, I would appreciate it if someone could reference a book or a paper where the assertion is proved for more general domains.

Comment: Chapter 3 of the book by Adams, Sobolev spaces, deals with related topics. Did you check it?

Comment: Hi Giorgio. Yes, I took a look at it. I could not find what I was looking for. That chapter deals mainly with the problem of understanding for which $\Omega$ one has $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)=W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. Did you have a specific result in mind (in that book)?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. Just similarity with your question.